# How to handle large number of associated products in bundle products?

Tags: magento2, bundled-product, associated-products

I am facing problem in handling large number of associated products to a **bundle product**. I have around **50k** associated products and page takes around **a minute** to load which is very slow and affects conversion rate and also adding product to cart also takes around **2 mins** and same for cart page load.

Is there any workaround or approach to deal with issue ?

PS: Open to do any sort of customization needed which can work.

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: did you have 50k associated product assigned to one bundled product?

Comment: Yes and may be we have to increase it to around 1 lacs or so in future.